# Can applepay technology be used to pay for metro rail and fares?

Tags: apple-pay

In Los Angeles county, we have a tap card system where you hold it against the surface on a reader and it deducts the card value from the card. Can iphone smartphones with applepay be used as a proxy to these tap cards? Are the technologies compatible?

Edit:

According to Wikipedia, the tap cards are based on rfid: en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contactless_smart_card#Technology

Apple pay is also based on rfid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, No. Not at this time.

Thank you,

Regional TAP Service Center
866-TAPTOGO (866-827-8646) 
http://www.taptogo.net/

-----Original Message-----

Subject: Is taptogo compatible with applepay?

Answer (score 0):

Only if the Los Angeles county department that deals with payments have made their systems compatible with Apple Pay. You will need to ask this question of them.

Comment: Sounds like you're not familiar with the technology that tap uses...